# Why is my app running out of memory? Unsetting variables, using chunk

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the simple app below.  I'm turning off query logging in Laravel, I'm unsetting where possible, yet this function will only process about 800 records before I'm out of RAM on my 2GB Linode.  I know I'm asking a lot of you guys but I can't seem to see where I'm leaking memory.

There are really only two major steps.

**Step 1 - Move records from a temp table to production**

```
class ListingMigrator
{
    public function __construct($tempListing, $feed)
    {
        $this->tempListing = $tempListing;
        $this->listing = $this->listingInstance();
        $this->feed = $feed;
    }

    public static function migrateListing($listing, $feed)
    {
        $instance = new static($listing, $feed);
        return $instance->migrate();
    }

    public function migrate()
    {
        $this->addExternalData();
        $this->populateListing();
        $this->processPhotos();
        $this->deleteTempListing();
    }

    private function listingInstance()
    {
        DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
        $listing = Listing::findByMud($this->tempListing->matrix_unique_id);
        return $listing ?: new Listing;
    }

    private function processPhotos()
    {
        $retsApi = new RetsFeedApi($this->feed);
        /* Initialize Object */
        $rets = $retsApi->findMostRecent();
        $photos = $rets->getPhotosForListing($this->listing->matrix_unique_id);
                        foreach ($photos as $photo)
                        {
                            $uploader = new PhotoProcessor($this->listing, $photo);
                            $uploader->process();
                        }
    }

    private function populateListing()
    {
        DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
        $this->listing->fill($this->tempListing->toArray());
        $this->listing->imported_at = $this->tempListing->created_at;
        $this->listing->board = $this->tempListing->board;

        return $this->listing->save();
    }

    private function addExternalData()
    {
        // Get Google lattitude and longitude
        $googlecoords = getGoogleMapInfo($this->tempListing->FullAddress, $this->tempListing->City);
        $this->listing->GoogleLat = $googlecoords['GoogleLat'];
        $this->listing->GoogleLong = $googlecoords['GoogleLong'];

        // Add or update the Subdivision Table (helper function)
        $subdivisiondata = SubdivisionUpdate($this->tempListing->board, $this->tempListing->SubCondoName, $this->tempListing->Development);
        $this->listing->SubdivisionID = $subdivisiondata['id'];
    }

    private function deleteTempListing()
    {
        return $this->tempListing->delete();
    }
}
```

**Step 2 - Download photos and reupload to Amazon S3**

```
class PhotoProcessor
{
  public function __construct(Listing $listing, $photoData)
  {
    $this->bucket       = 'real-estate-listings';
    $this->s3           = App::make('aws')->get('s3');
    $this->tempFileName = 'app/storage/processing/images/retsphotoupload';
    $this->photoData    = $photoData;
    $this->listing      = $listing;
    $this->photo        = new RetsPhoto;
  }

  public function process()
  {
    $this->storeTempFile();
    $this->storeFileInfo();
    $this->buildPhoto();

    $success = $this->pushToS3();

    // if Result has the full URL or you want to build it, add it to $this->photo
    DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
    $this->listing->photos()->save($this->photo);  
    $this->removeTempFile();
    unset ($this->photoData);
    return $success;
  }

  private function storeTempFile()
  {
    return File::put($this->tempFileName, $this->photoData['Data']) > 0;
  }

  private function storeFileInfo()
  {
    $fileInfo = getimagesize($this->tempFileName);
    // Could even be its own object
    $this->fileInfo = [
    'width'     => $fileInfo[0],
    'height'    => $fileInfo[1],
    'mimetype'  => $fileInfo['mime'],
    'extension' => $this->getFileExtension($fileInfo['mime'])
    ];
  }

  private function buildPhoto()
  {
    $this->photo->number = $this->photoData['Object-ID']; // Storing this because it is relevant order wise
    $this->photo->width  = $this->fileInfo['width'];
    $this->photo->height = $this->fileInfo['height'];
    $this->photo->path   = $this->getFilePath();
  }

  private function getFilePath()
  {
    $path   = [];
    if ($this->listing->City == NULL)
    {
      $path[] = Str::slug('No City');
    }
    else
    {
      $path[] = Str::slug($this->listing->City, $separator = '-'); 
    }

    if ($this->listing->Development == NULL)
    {
      $path[] = Str::slug('No Development');
    }
    else
    {
      $path[] = Str::slug($this->listing->Development, $separator = '-');  
    }

    if ($this->listing->Subdivision == NULL)
    {
      $pathp[] = Str::slug('No Subdivision');
    }
    else
    {
      $path[] = Str::slug($this->listing->Subdivision, $separator = '-');  
    }

    if ($this->listing->MLSNumber == NULL)
    {
      $pathp[] = Str::slug('No MLSNumber');
    }
    else
    {
      $path[] = Str::slug($this->listing->MLSNumber, $separator = '-');
    }

      $path[] = $this->photoData['Object-ID'].'.'.$this->fileInfo['extension'];

      return strtolower(join('/', $path));
  }

  private function pushToS3()
  {
    return $this->s3->putObject([
      'Bucket'     => $this->bucket,
      'Key'        => $this->photo->path,
      'ContentType'=> $this->fileInfo['mimetype'],
      'SourceFile' => $this->tempFileName
    ]);
  }

  private function getFileExtension($mime)
  {
    // Use better algorithm than this
    $ext = str_replace('image/', '', $mime);
    return $ext == 'jpeg' ? 'jpg' : $ext;
  }

  private function removeTempFile()
  {
    return File::delete($this->tempFileName);
  }
}
```

**Edit to show RetsPhoto**

```
class RetsPhoto extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'rets_property_photos';

    public function listing() {

        return $this->belongsTo('Listing', 'matrix_unique_id', 'matrix_unique_id');
    }

}
```

**Edit #2:  Chunk Call**
This is in the app/command and the only thing in there is the fire() function below:

```
public function fire()
{
    // Turn off query logging
    DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();

    $feeds = RetsFeed::where('active','=',1)->get();
    foreach ($feeds as $feed)
    {

        $class = "TempListing{$feed->board}";

        $listings = $class::orderBy('MatrixModifiedDT','desc');

        $listings->chunk(50, function($listings) use($feed) {
            $listings->each(function($listing) use ($feed) {
                ListingMigrator::migrateListing($listing,$feed);
                echo "Feed: $feed->board\r\n";
                echo "SubcondoName: $listing->SubCondoName\r\n";
                echo "Development: $listing->Development\r\n";
                echo "\r\n";
            });
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I have a feeling `getimagesize` loads the resource into memory.

Comment: @Marty how would I tell?

Comment: I am trying to find out for certain at the moment, as well as how to release that memory.

Comment: You could try using `imagecreatefromjpeg` and getting the image size from that, then use `imagedestroy` on it, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: this concerns me... $this->photo        = new RetsPhoto;  Please update post with that class.

Comment: Where's your `chunk` call?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured it out.

1. Your system holds in memory all of the photo data. As witnessed by the  unset ($this->photoData);

   2. The problem is that you need to first complete the process function. Your application is not likely processing ANY photos so when you keep grabbing them from the file system you run out of memory BEFORE you even process a single one.

To Confirm this, simply grab 1 file not using the chunk method.
I am not very familar with Laravel, it could be grabbing all of the files all at once as well and eating the ram.

You can do some tracing with memory_get_usage(true) to find out exactly where the ram is getting eaten from. I would suggest analysing the fire method first.

Comment: I don't know.  It's pulling in all of the photos for one record in a temp table and migrating that one record over to a master table, downloading and reuploading the images to S3 and then moving on.  It downloading the images one at a time.